# Send an image over a network

Tags: python, c++, qt, opencv

I've asked [a question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578456/sending-structured-data-over-a-network) about sending structured data over network, and how to deal with those data on server side.

What I'm actualy trying to do, is sending an image over a network from client side (c++/Qt) to server side (python).

both sides are using [OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/)

and I've found these OpenCV functions that could help me I think: [`cv::imencode()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode), [`cv::imdecode()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode)

Sending part (client side):

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.png")

vector<uchar> buf;
cv::imencode( ".png", img, buf );

// rawImage: the data that are supposed to be sended and decoded with cv2.imdecode() 
QByteArray rawImage = QByteArray( (const char *) buf.data(), buf.size() );

// construct paquet
QByteArray sep = QByteArray();
sep.append( "<break>" );

QByteArray paquet;
paquet.append( _token );
paquet.append( sep );
paquet.append( query );
paquet.append( sep );
paquet.append( QJsonDocument( jsonObject ).toJson( QJsonDocument::Compact ) );
paquet.append( sep );
paquet.append( rawImage );
write( paquet );
```

Receiving part (server side)

```
# get the data here...
lines = data.split( '<break>' )
raw = lines[3]
img = cv2.imdecode( raw, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR )
# process img ...
```

I've got this error:

```
...
img = cv2.imdecode( raw, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR )
exceptions.TypeError: buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I think it's not the better way to send (or encode) this image. some help ?

**EDIT:** 
I think that the OpenCV fonctions are not compatible between the C++ and the Python version, and the images are not stored the same way in memory. Someone to confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-part request to avoid encoding/decoding, it allows to upload image and key/value pairs simultaneously. In PHP, image uploaded with multi-part request will be accessible through `$_FILES` variable. Can be implemented with `QHttpMultiPart` class.